# how compare a str object with None

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have meet a problem, when I develop a web use python3+flask, when name has no in put, I am confused, the result is True in print

```
name = request.args.get('name')
if name is not None:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

I refer to python documents, "A is not B" means A and B is not same object.
And I make the following test:

```
print(name) #None
print(type(name)) #<class "str">
print(type(None)) #<class "NoneType">
```

I found the answer, but when I use the following format

```
if name:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

it prints True and print(name) I get None
I have to write like the following:

```
if name != str(None):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

I feel it a little uncomfortable when use it like this, how I can compare it in a elegant way.

Comment: It sounds like `name` contains the string `'None'`. Are you expecting it to have a different value?

Comment: thanks very much. that is it. how stupid I am, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a string "None" as part of a request commonly happens when you return a `None` value as part of a previous response.

Example:

```
# given a variable that is passed to a jinja template as None
# instead of as an empty string
name = None
```

Will result in a link with "None" as a string.

```
<a href="/some/link?name={{ name }}>click here</a>
```

Instead of trying to handle for a string "None" in any given request where you expect a string, you should output the original variable as an empty string:

```
name = None
...

# convert Nones to empty strings right before sending to jinja
if not name:
    name = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(True if "None" not in name else False)
```

I think that's more elegant way of printing out in your case.